# Splitting strings in a list of strings and appending them

Tags: python

Given a list of strings, I want to split each string separately when it finds a specific character.

For example:
I've got an array with a single string in it
Array = ['SomeText SomeMoreText EvenMoreText']

At every space I want everything to the left of it to become its own value.

Array = ['SomeText', 'SomeMoreText', 'EvenMoreText']

Comment: Are you going to have always only one element/string in the list? How do you end up with one-element list in the first place?

Comment: Just to be clear, these are a `list` type, *not* an array.  These are *very* different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

*For example: ive got an array with a **single string in it***

Since there is a single string in the list.

```
Array = ['SomeText SomeMoreText EvenMoreText']
```

you can do:

```
Array = Array[-1].split()
```

or

```
Array = Array[0].split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = ["Here is some text"]
arr = arr[0].split()
print(arr)
//['Here', 'is', 'some', 'text']
```

The `split()` method called for `arr[0]` splits the 0th element of `arr` by whitespaces (by default). Then the return of the method is put into the `arr` array.

Comment: How @buran said, this code is not the best idea in the first place. You should probably get a single string element  `s = "Here is some text"` and then put it into the list (the thing you probably want is a list as @S3DEV said, thanks) like this: `my_list = s.split()`. This code looks perfectly fine to me